# jquery .load keeps firing javascript after .remove

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm making a chat with the simple javascript:

```
<script>
function chatClick(messages_other_user) {
    $('#chatBox').remove();
    document.body.innerHTML += "<div id='chatBox' class='chatDiv'></div>";
    $("#chatBox").load("subs/chat/chat.php?ou="+messages_other_user);
}
</script>
```

This function is called in several links with the variable "messages_other_user" changing.

In the file "chat.php" I get the variable of "ou" and I have a script that writes to the console:

```
if (isset($_GET['ou'])) { $otherUserChat = $_GET['ou']; } else $otherUserChat = 0; // get $otherUserChat 

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    var chatUpdateVar = setInterval(function() {
        console.log("<?= $otherUserChat ?>");
    }, 2000);
    $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
});
</script>
```

But the .remove line doesn't quite get rid of the javascript in the chat.php file. When I click a link to call the javascript chatClick function, it works fine. But when I then click another link that calls chatClick with a different variable for "messages_other_user" the old one keeps firing along with the new one.

How can I destroy the old javascript completely so it doesn't run anymore?

Comment: I don't understand your question but, I advice to you, you can use .html('') method. This is help for remove and again add your element.

Comment: Please share the code for binding the JS function with your "link"

Comment: Sameer - 

The links are generated in a PHP loop; it loops through all rows in a SQL call, which finds the $messages_other_user and outputs it like so:  
  
    <a onclick="chatClick(<?= $messages_other_user ?>Text</a>

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution - and I was mistaken by the true culprit of the issue.

I thought a console.log would yield the same result as what I truly do - I just chose to replace with console.log in the code for simplicity. So I guess I've learned that's a stupid thing to do.

What is actually happening in the chat.php file in the document ready script is this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var chatUpdateVar = setInterval(function() {
    $("#chatArea").load("subs/chat/chatContent.php?ou="+<?= $otherUserChat ?>);
    console.log("updated");
}, 4000);
});
```

I figured out I didn't readlly need to use the document ready, so I instead, I just do this directly in my script:

```
var chatUpdateVar = setInterval(function() {
    $("#chatArea").load("subs/chat/chatContent.php?ou="+<?= $otherUserChat ?>);
    console.log("updated");
}, 4000); // CHECK FOR UNREAD: 1000 equals 1 second
$.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
```

For closing the chat window, I now trigger this function:

```
function closeChat() {
    clearInterval(chatUpdateVar);
    $('#chatBox').remove();
}
```

And in the file that calls the above script (chat.php), I check if the function closeChat exists - and if it does, I run it. This is part of the cal to the chat.php:

```
function chatClick(messages_other_user) {
    if (typeof closeChat === "function") { 
        closeChat();
    }

    document.body.innerHTML += "<div id='chatBox' class='chatDiv'></div>";
    $("#chatBox").load("subs/chat/chat.php?ou="+messages_other_user);
}
```